# Why does organ transplant work although it seems organ's motor neuron isn't connected to recipient's CNS

Tags: organs, transplantation

Although it seems impossible with current technology to connect organ's capillaries to the recipient's capillaries and its motor neuron to the CNS, transplanted organ works for years. But why?

Comment: could you specify which organ you are talking about?

Comment: How about kidney?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capillaries only transport blood for short distances, and within an organ. The blood supply to/from a major organ is generally carried over a few major blood vessels (usually one artery, one vein). Splicing such larger blood vessels are what surgeons earn their pay to do.

In terms of nerves, [most transplanted organs function fairly well without being connected to the CNS](http://www.quora.com/Surgery/How-do-transplanted-organs-function-without-nerve-connections).

Comment: With respect to OP comment asking about kidney and this fine simple answer, with a kidney you just have a renal artery, a renal vein, and a ureter that need to be connected. Internal vessels and tubules of kidney handled the rest. There are nerves innervating the kidney, but last I knew their function was still "an area of active research interest."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which surprised me a lot. After changing key words on google search, I found several new results. One of them was about heart transplant, and it also works totally fine, except for the fact that the transplanted heart beats faster, responds more slowly to exercise and doesn't increase its rate as quickly as before. I'm expecting to see further development in organ transplant technology, so that transplanted organ will work even better.